# Include Bourbon path in package.json?

Tags: json, node.js, sass, npm, bourbon

How is it possible to include paths to Bourbon (installed via npm) in a package.json of a node project?

All the examples I've seen are via grunt, etc:

```
var bourbon = require('node-bourbon');
bourbon.includePaths // Array of Bourbon paths
```

Anyone know how to do this so that the following will work in SASS files?

```
@import 'bourbon';
```

Current SASS compilation is a step in our build that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    // Need to import bourbon npm package as sass before /scss directory
    "sass": "node-sass -o build/css/ scss/"
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You want to set paths? Or access them from SASS? Or what?

Comment: @SteveBennett I've edited the post for clarity. Basically I need to import the bourbon npm package at the top of my compiled scss build file. If you look at the [node-sass docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) there seems to be an `--include-path` method, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, but as far as i know it's not possible to set the include path in the package.json.

If you are using the Sass CLI you can run `sass -I [path to bourbon] input.scss:output.css`

Using `node-sass` would be:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass --include-path node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets -o build/css/ scss/"
}
```

Comment: I've edited the post for clarity. Basically I need to import the bourbon npm package at the top of my compiled scss build file. If you look at the [node-sass docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) there seems to be an `--include-path` method, but it's not working for me.

Comment: `--include-path` works for me. Edited the answer to include the code